# how to get the time duration video watched in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am making an iphone app in which playing video from url server it works fine but i want lets say video is for 3 minutes or 4 minutes how much time user viewed video like it played video for 1 minuted and stoped likewise.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:newString];
NSLog(@"New File name is %@",newString);            
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
[[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
//[[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can start `NSTimer` at the time of presenting `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and listen the notification `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` or `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey` and calculate the time.

**EDIT**

Best way is to access MPMediaPlayback's `currentPlaybackTime` property using `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification

this will give you the actual time.
In your case you can access this property as

```
  NSTimeInterval time =  mp.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
```

Comment: what if internet is slow and 2 mintues video take 5 mintues to play

Answer (score 0):

If u check the reference manual `MPMoviePlayerController` conforms to `MPMediaPlayback` protocol

So `MPMediaPlayback` protocol contains the property

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime
```

The current position of the playhead. (required)

**Example**:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
...

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = player.currentPlaybackTime;
```

**Links :**

[MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953)

[MPMediaPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notification center:

1- On viewDidLoad:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)
                                          name:@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

2- Implement this method (seconds is an int):

```
- (void)playbackStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"note.name=%@ state=%d", note.name, [[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue]);

if ([[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue] == 2) {
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(increaseSeconds) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"seconds: %i", seconds);
} else if([[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue] == 1){
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"seconds: %i", seconds);
} else if([[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue] == 0){
    NSLog(@"Total watched: %i", seconds);

    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

}

where MPAVControllerNewStateParameter == 2 (video started)
      MPAVControllerNewStateParameter == 1 (video stopped)
      MPAVControllerNewStateParameter == 0 (video finished or pressed "Done")

3- Finally implement this method:

```
-(void) increaseSeconds {
    seconds++;
}
```